# How to identify first class between others class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, identify

I have one link with some divs class:

```
<a class='div1 otherdiv alignleft'>Link</a>
```

I need to call a function to the first class of this link, as I can get the name of this class in a variable?

Remembering that the name of the first div will not be fixed name, so I can't declare something like this: *var firstdiv = div1*

So how can I get the name of the first class and store in a variable? in order to use it in a function?
Something Like this:

```
var firstdiv = ('a').first();
```

And call function with this var:

```
$(firstdiv).click(function(){
    // my function
});
```

How can I identify **name** of the first div that is within the tag **a**?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  But I think you're looking for `$("a:first")`.  Are you?

Comment: and FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: I don't see any names or div tags in your question.. do you mean 'class name' of A tags? or there should be <div></div> elements inside the A tags?

Comment: $("a ...")[0] ... and remember ids have to be unique or you'll run into strange problems later.

Comment: @A.M.K check this [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/H6LGJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/H6LGJ/). Eyal Barta yes, check this fiddle too please. A. Wolff yes, i know, thanks anyway. rupps yes, thanks.

Comment: I remake the question, please read again.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to do "$(firstdiv).click(...", simply "firstdiv.click(..." will work.

Comment: I would just use data attributes for this! You shouldn't have to worry abotu what order you have the class names...that just seems brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple like that http://jsfiddle.net/hj8Vb/

**HTML**

```
<div id="bla" class="div1 another align test">Content</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#bla').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a > div:first')

|OR|

$.('a > div').first()
```

See Also: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Or, if you already assigned the click to the `a tag`, you could do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var firstDiv = $(this).children('div').first();
    alert(firstDiv.attr('name');
});
```

See Also:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Please check this: [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/H6LGJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/H6LGJ/), what is wrong?